Percentage difference in the same column between two item groups
I want to calculate which houses have more than a 10% difference (Qty column) between two different groups of items in the same column (Item).
I will use this to calculate which house has more sqft of the ceiling than the floor.
I'm using percentage difference: the absolute value of the change in value divided by the average of the two numbers, all multiplied by 100. |V1-V2|/((V1+V2)/2)*100
My data table "Property_1"



House_ID
Item
Qty




1
Ceiling type 1
50


1
Ceiling type 2
50


1
Floor type 1
100


2
Ceiling type 1
100


2
Floor type 1
50


3
Floor type 1
30


3
Ceiling type 1
50


4
Ceiling type 2
500


4
Floor type 1
90


4
Floor type 2
50



Results



House_ID
Difference_%




2
66


3
50


4
113



So far, I have created a query:
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Property_1 WHERE Item IN ('Ceiling type 1', 'Ceiling type 2', 'Ceiling type 3')) -
    (SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Property_1 WHERE Item IN ('Floor type 1', 'Floor type 2'))
AS Total_Qty_Difference
GROUP BY House_ID;


What calculation are you using to get those percentage differences?

I'm using percentage difference: the absolute value of the change in value divided by the average of the 2 numbers, all multiplied by 100. |V1-V2|/((V1+V2)/2)*100


I want to calculate which houses have more than a 10% difference (Qty column) between two different groups of items in the same column (Item).

Use conditional aggregation to find the totals for each group and then check if the lesser value of the two groups is 10% below the greater value:
SELECT house_id,
       ceiling,
       floor,
       (GREATEST(ceiling, floor) / LEAST(ceiling, floor) - 1) * 100
         AS percent_difference
FROM   (       
  SELECT house_id,
         SUM(
           CASE 
           WHEN item IN ('Ceiling type 1', 'Ceiling type 2', 'Ceiling type 3')
           THEN Qty
           END
         ) AS ceiling,
         SUM(
           CASE 
           WHEN item IN ('Floor type 1', 'Floor type 2', 'Floor type 3')
           THEN Qty
           END
         ) AS floor
  FROM   Property_1
  GROUP BY house_id
)
WHERE  GREATEST(ceiling, floor) > LEAST(ceiling, floor) * 1.10

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE Property_1 (House_ID, Item, Qty) AS
SELECT 1, 'Ceiling type 1',  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Ceiling type 2',  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Floor type 1',   100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Ceiling type 1', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Floor type 1',    50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Floor type 1',    30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Ceiling type 1',  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Ceiling type 2', 500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Floor type 1',    90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Floor type 2',    50 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



HOUSE_ID
CEILING
FLOOR
PERCENT_DIFFERENCE




2
100
50
100


3
50
30
66.666666667


4
500
140
257.1428571





I will use this to calculate which house has more [square foot] of the ceiling than the floor.

If you still want a 10% difference and ceiling > floor then use:
SELECT house_id,
       ceiling,
       floor,
       (ceiling / floor - 1) * 100 AS percent_difference
FROM   (       
  SELECT house_id,
         SUM(
           CASE 
           WHEN item IN ('Ceiling type 1', 'Ceiling type 2', 'Ceiling type 3')
           THEN Qty
           END
         ) AS ceiling,
         SUM(
           CASE 
           WHEN item IN ('Floor type 1', 'Floor type 2', 'Floor type 3')
           THEN Qty
           END
         ) AS floor
  FROM   Property_1
  GROUP BY house_id
)
WHERE  ceiling > floor * 1.10

Which has the same output for your sample data.

If you want to use your calculation for the percentage of difference divided by average then:
SELECT house_id,
       ceiling,
       floor,
       ABS(ceiling - floor) / (floor + ceiling) * 200
         AS percent_difference
FROM   (       
  SELECT house_id,
         SUM(
           CASE 
           WHEN item IN ('Ceiling type 1', 'Ceiling type 2', 'Ceiling type 3')
           THEN Qty
           END
         ) AS ceiling,
         SUM(
           CASE 
           WHEN item IN ('Floor type 1', 'Floor type 2', 'Floor type 3')
           THEN Qty
           END
         ) AS floor
  FROM   Property_1
  GROUP BY house_id
)
WHERE  ABS(ceiling - floor) / (floor + ceiling) * 200 > 10

Which outputs:



HOUSE_ID
CEILING
FLOOR
PERCENT_DIFFERENCE




2
100
50
66.66666666666666666666666666666666666666


3
50
30
50


4
500
140
112.5



fiddle

@TheRealMichaelScott Fixed and also added another option for your percentage calculation.

Amazing! Great Job! Thank you

Assuming you want the percentage based on floor square footage. Items provided starts either as Floor or Ceiling, so you could use first few letters to make a distinction between the two. It would be better to have some kind of surface id, though.
Use Having clause to filter the resultset (more than 10%):
WITH     --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", 'Ceiling type 1' "ITEM",  50 "QTY" From Dual Union All
          Select 1, 'Ceiling type 2',  50 From Dual Union All
          Select 1, 'Floor type 1',   100 From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 'Ceiling type 1', 100 From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 'Floor type 1',    50 From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 'Floor type 1',    30 From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 'Ceiling type 1',  50 From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 'Ceiling type 2', 500 From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 'Floor type 1',    90 From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 'Floor type 2',    50 From Dual
       )

--     S Q L :
Select    ID, 
          Sum( Case When SubStr(ITEM, 1, 5) = 'Floor' Then QTY Else 0 End ) "FLOOR", 
          Sum( Case When SubStr(ITEM, 1, 5) = 'Ceili' Then QTY Else 0 End ) "CEILING",
          --
          -- PCT = (Ceiling - Floor) * 100 / Floor
          ( Sum( Case When SubStr(ITEM, 1, 5) = 'Ceili' Then QTY Else 0 End )
           - Sum( Case When SubStr(ITEM, 1, 5) = 'Floor' Then QTY Else 0 End )
          ) * 100 / Sum( Case When SubStr(ITEM, 1, 5) = 'Floor' Then QTY Else 0 End )  "PCT"
From      tbl
Group By  ID
Having    -- PCT > 10 
         ( Sum( Case When SubStr(ITEM, 1, 5) = 'Ceili' Then QTY Else 0 End )
           - Sum( Case When SubStr(ITEM, 1, 5) = 'Floor' Then QTY Else 0 End )
          ) * 100 / Sum( Case When SubStr(ITEM, 1, 5) = 'Floor' Then QTY Else 0 End ) > 10
Order By  ID

/*    R e s u l  t :
        ID      FLOOR    CEILING        PCT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2         50        100        100
         3         30         50 66,6666667
         4        140        500 257,142857    */

